# How much capacity inverters and batteries should i need to set up a 800 watts solar panel?

Tags: solar-power, home

my requirement is just to run ten 4-watts LEDs, a 0.5 HP submursible motor and four ceiling fans through solar panels. Calculations suggested that i need 800 watts panels to work on it. But I'm unaware of batteries and inverters. The place where i would be setting this is a new plotted area, so no previous electricity records. Can you please help me out of this ?

Comment: What's your actual power requirement (maximum load, daily energy use), and how long do you need to run with little or no solar input (days)? Those are the three key numbers that drive everything else, and without them we can't help you much. Will you have a backup generator? Without it you'll need more panels and more batteries. The latter numbers depend on exactly where you are, so without that we can't help. [This question](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/how-can-i-cheaply-evaluate-how-much-solar-energy-i-can-collect) has some suggestions on estimate solar yeild

Comment: Motors typically have a higher startup current/watt requirement. Make sure that Inverter is able to provide a higher wattage for several seconds.